# getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException when using Lucene-PDFbox jar

Tags: java, lucene, pdfbox, pdf-extraction

When I am running this code, I am getting following Exception. Running fine with only PDFBox jar. getting this exception Lucene-PDFBox jar only.

```
 import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
 import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.lucene.LucenePDFDocument;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;

 Document doc1 = LucenePDFDocument.getDocument(new 
 File("C:\\Users\\E075551\\Downloads\\resume.pdf"));
 System.out.println("END-------"+doc1.getFields().get(1));
```

Throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException

**Traces are :**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/exceptions/CryptographyException
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.utils.PDFUtils.getContentRow(PDFUtils.java:118)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.workflows.customer.cardmanagement.ReportVerificationWorkflow.getReportContent(ReportVerificationWorkflow.java:77)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.workflows.customer.cardmanagement.ReportVerificationWorkflow.verifyGenericReport(ReportVerificationWorkflow.java:70)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.workflows.customer.cardmanagement.ReportVerificationWorkflow.verifyGenericReport(ReportVerificationWorkflow.java:54)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.workflows.customer.cardmanagement.ReportVerificationWorkflow$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c86b4458.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.aop.ReportingAspect.proceedAndReportStep(ReportingAspect.java:47)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.aop.ReportingAspect.proceedStep(ReportingAspect.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:620)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:609)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.workflows.customer.cardmanagement.ReportVerificationWorkflow$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab939610.verifyGenericReport(<generated>)
    at com.mastercard.pts.integrated.issuing.steps.customer.cardmanagement.ReportVerificationSteps.validateGenericReport(ReportVerificationSteps.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:733)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$FineSoFar.run(PerformableTree.java:346)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableSteps.perform(PerformableTree.java:1088)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$AbstractPerformableScenario.performRestartableSteps(PerformableTree.java:953)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$NormalPerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:992)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:902)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.performScenarios(PerformableTree.java:825)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.perform(PerformableTree.java:798)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performCancellable(PerformableTree.java:422)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.perform(PerformableTree.java:393)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:292)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Can you please some more code like the entire class here? Looks like it cannot somehow find your `CryptographyException`, can you check if this is available in your repository!

Comment: I do not need to declare the CryptographyException. Document.getFields() throwing this exception.

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies?

Comment: ok, somewhere in your `(PDFUtils.java:118)` is there anything hinting towards something that is required but is missing? (or probably the one's that are utilizing this util class of yours?) To me I'm sure it looks like the dependency is  missing this `org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException`

Comment: @Compass Through Maven. and it doesn't show any missing library.

Comment: @robot_alien Nope it is not hinting towards something. This can be a issue in Lucene-PDFBox jar.

Comment: please do a complete clean build on your maven project and refresh your IDE in that case...

Comment: @robot_alien did that still getting the same Exception.

Comment: Can we get the pom? I believe it might be an unmapped transitive dependency.

Comment: LucenePDFDocument is from PDFBox 1.8 and it is dependent of pdfbox.